# How to write xpath with variable?

Tags: selenium2, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have an xpath:

```
//*[@id='00QE000000gQ9fv_ACTION_COLUMN']/a[2]/span
```

in this xpath *00QE000000gQ9fv* is dynamic and *_ACTION_COLUMN* remains the same.
I stored *00QE000000gQ9fv* in a String variable as recordId i.e:

```
String recordId = 00QE000000gQ9fv
```

Now I want an xpath that contains recordId variable.

Comment: Just concatenate the string?
See the reply on this question.
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12299/how-to-get-unique-xpath-with-dynamic-id/12300#12300

Answer (score 4):

Create a string variable and use it (for example) as follows:

```
string strMyXPath = "//*[@id='" + recordId + "_ACTION_COLUMN']/a[2]/span";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(strMyXPath)).Click();
```

Comment: this works perfectly right and working fine for my code.